# Is there any way to enable Full Text Search on installed sql2008,without uninstalling it again

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to enable Full Text Search on installed sql2008,without uninstalling it again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you didn't install it as an optional component at the time of install, then running the installer again should detect the existing SQL Server instance.  You can then pick it as an additional option to install and it will only install that component.

You should be able to re-run the installer from add/remove programs or the SQL Server DVD.

Comment: no, you don't need to re-install. The setup will not re-install components that are already there!

Comment: We've got a failure to communicate here.  PRG - if you think "reinstall" means rerunning setup.exe, then yes, you're right, but this won't require uninstalling and installing the SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe you installed it but it isn't working, you may find that your "SQL Server Full-text Daemon Launcher" service is disabled. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services. Find the "SQL Server Full-text Daemon Launcher" entry, right click and select properties then enable it and start the service.

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search is on by default but it is possible to toggle it on specific tables.  [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142536.aspx) is a tutorial on how to enable and disable full-text search in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: But when iam going to enable in the same way what tutorial said,that option is not active can u pleas give me the solution for this,or i have to reinstall again???